# Can a plant base have taste buds?

Tags: science-based, biology, xenobiology, flora

The question is in the title.  Is there an existing plant that do have taste buds? If they can have taste buds, what taste buds they can have? Just in case they has less or more taste buds than human, correct me if I am wrong because I at least know cats can't taste sweetness.

> as expected for the spawn of satan!

And if they have taste buds, is there a restriction on plant organs that can only generate it, like only in the leaves, roots, or the wood or all parts can generate it?

I personally think they do has, considering they generate sweet or sour and even know spiciness like chili capsaicin, but I ask just to be sure.

I need to know this to see what kind of food taste they will considered as delicacy or the type of cooking they prefer.  Also from what I found seems like carnivore plant cant eat fat and it dangerous for them.

the plant I mean here is mean for both or general plants types, not just carnivore plants.

feel free to correct my grammar and add the correct tag to this, since I don't know what tag is more appropriate for this.

Comment: they can have flower, leaf or shoot buds, but they don't have taste buds

Comment: Plants generate tastes either accidentally, as a byproduct of their chemistry, or for the animals that might eat them.  Sweetness attracts animals that distribute seeds; bitterness or spice repeal animals.

Comment: they probably could, don't know why you would ever want that but ok

Comment: check this out - Allelopathy

Comment: A taste bud is just a place where cells that have chemoreceptive ability live. If plants are able to detect chemical compounds, then they basically already have taste buds of a sort.

Answer (score 3):

Ethylene (C2H4)is an important plant hormone. It is best know for helping to control the ripening of fruit - but it is also associated with many complex aspects of plant growth including seed germination, root development, shoot and root growth, leaves dropping in autumn and flower and fruit development.

Ethylene is also produced in response to a variety of stresses, such as drought, flooding and viral and fungal infections.

There is also some (less compelling) evidence that plants produce ethylene when they are attacked by insects. In theory the ethylene stimulates production of chemicals in the plant's own cells and these chemicals discourage the insects from eating or damaging the plant any further.

Ethylene is very volatile and in theory it could get blown through the atmosphere from one plant that is being attacked by insects to nearby plants (not necessarily even of the same species) and can trigger their own production of defensive chemicals, in this way the ethylene acts as a pheromone.

This doesn't really count as plants being able to taste. But you might be able to say they can 'smell' at least one chemical - ethylene.